# Funcion de dos array

Tags: php, array, function

tengo una duda esta funcion esta en php pero al ejecutarla no me muestra nada y no se por que según yo esta correcta

```
  function ciudadesUnicas(array $array1, array $array2) : array
   {
return [];  
  }

  $ciudades = ciudadesUnicas(['Madrid', 'Londres', 'París', 'Madrid'], ['París', 'Copenhague', 'Londres']);

   print_r(join(",",$ciudades));
```

Comment: Esa función solamente retorna un array vacío. Supongo que deberás poner el resto del código dentro de la función, antes del `return`.

Comment: La función no hace ninguna operación

Answer (score 0):

Como bien especificaron en los comentarios la función "ciudadesUnicas" retorna un arreglo vacio (no hace nada mas).

Si quieres combinar dos o mas arreglos puedes usar la función [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-merge.php).

Luego si quieres eliminar los nombres de ciudades duplicados puedes utilizar la función [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php) sobre el arreglo que retornó "array_merge".

El código lo podrías agregar en el cuerpo de la función "ciudadesUnicas", y retornar el arreglo resultante.